# Re-using subscriptions inside flatMapLatest

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the following RxJS definition:

```
onIds
    .flatMapLatest((ids) => Rx.Observable
      .from(ids)
      .flatMap((id) => onUpdated(id)))
```

Which works well. However, `onUpdated` is an expensive subscription to restart (i.e. it has a socket connection). So what I'd much prefer if there was a way to re-use subscriptions from previous `ids` instances, however I am unsure how to achieve that in a pragmatic way...

EDIT:

The best I can come up with is something like:

```
function cached(factory) {
  return (id) => {
    const cache = factory._cached_cache || (factory._cached_cache = new Map())
    const x = cache.get(id)
    return x ? x : Rx.Observable.defer(() => {
        const x = factory(id)
          .finally(() => cache.delete(id))
          .share()
        cache.set(id, x)
        return x
      })
    }
}

onIds
    .flatMapLatest((ids) => Rx.Observable
      .from(ids)
      .flatMap(cached(onUpdatedCache))
```

Answer (score 2):

It would help to post a little more about `onUpdated`.  Without knowing more, I'd say the solution is most likely to use some Dependency Injection techniques to pass the live socket connection as an argument to `onUpdated` instead of having that method create its own.

Either

```
Rx.Observable.using(
    () => new SocketConnection(...),
    socket => onIds.flatMapLatest(ids => Observable
        .from(ids)
        .flatMap(id => onUpdated(socket, id))));
```

Or with some encapsulation...

```
Rx.Observable.using(
    () => new Updater(...),
    updater => onIds.flatMapLatest(ids => Observable
        .from(ids)
        .flatMap(id => updater.onUpdated(id))));
```

Edit:

Based on your updated description, the only way I can think to do this, besides your memoization trick, is to model the actual entry and exit of an `id` from the `ids` array.  Something like this:

```
onIds
    .startWith([])
    .pairwise()
    .flatMap([prev, curr] => {
        // generate list of "added" and "removed" ids
        const added = curr.filter(id => prev.indexOf(id) === -1);
        const removed = prev.filter(id => curr.indexOf(id) === -1);

        // only emit ids when they are added and later removed
        return added.concat(removed);
    })
    .groupByUntil(
        id => id, // key selector
        null, // no need for element selector
        ids => ids.skip(1)) // end the group when the id is seen 2nd time (e.g. removed)
    .map(group => group.key)
    .flatMap(id => doUpdate(id));
```

Comment: That might help, but it does not solved the fundamental issue which as that the subscription should be reused. The best solution I have right now is to use a cache and release on `finally`.

Comment: what subscription?  Reused over what window?

Comment: The observable return by `onUpdated` will be subscribed by `combineLatest` or `merge` or whatever combinator. When the value of `flatMapLatest` is changed all those subscriptions will be thrown away and totally new ones will be created.

Comment: Something like this,https://gist.github.com/ronag/0325869c92d629b14899, could work but is very ugly...

Comment: ah so you want to stay subscribed to the "current" observable _per id_ until that observable finishes or the id is missing from a newer version of the array?

Comment: I have updated my post fix a suggestion for a hack fix.

Comment: ok took a stab at another way to do it.  I'm not sure if it is any better.

Comment: Need to think about that for a bit. Thanks!